# Divide money in MYSQL or BigDecimal Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to divide tax money in equal.

Problem statement: Customer purchase a products 3 qty. And the total tax on 3 qty is $10.

Now I have to fetch the tax per tax.
10 / 3 = 3.33

but in total it will not give me $10.

I have to solve this problem with MySQL.

```
SELECT OH.ORDER_ID, SUM(OA.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_TAX, OI.QUANTITY AS ORDERED_QTY, (SUM(OA.AMOUNT)/OI.QUANTITY) AS TAX_PER_QTY
FROM ORDER_HEADER OH,
     ORDER_ADJUSTMENT OA,
     ORDER_ITEM OI
WHERE AND OH.ORDER_ID = OA.ORDER_ID
  AND OH.ORDER_ID  ='SGSM11592'
  AND OI.ORDER_ID = OH.ORDER_ID
  AND OI.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID = OA.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID
group by OA.ORDER_ADJUSTMENT_TYPE_ID, OA.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID, OA.COMMENTS, OH.ORDER_ID, OA.SOURCE_PERCENTAGE
order by OI.ORDER_ITEM_SEQ_ID;
```

I don't have exact solution to deal with

**Can I do the same with BigDecimal java??**

Comment: what is the result it is giving you?

Comment: It's giving me 3.3333.
As simple as SELECT 10/3 in MYSQL

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN`  syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: There is no "exact solution". Either the final sum will slightly differ from desired one (9.9999 and 10) or some prices will slightly differ from another ones (3.3334 and 3.3333).

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY OH.ORDER_ID, OI.QUANTITY`.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: One way would be to make one row do the sum as 'expected - sum(other computed rounded values)' conditionally using a case, which would be a way to generate the 3.34. But that's not great. I'm not sure how else you'd do this in SQL: generate a temporary table in a sproc, check it's correct and modify it there or not?

Comment: remove `(SUM(OA.AMOUNT)/OI.QUANTITY) AS TAX_PER_QTY` and just keep  `SUM(OA.AMOUNT)` to see whats the outcome?

Comment: The outcome of SUM(OA.AMOUNT) is 10